# Access multiple web-frontends through an ingress controller within a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, frontend

I have a Kubernetes cluster with two applications which provide web-frontends, and I would like to make both of them accesible through an NGINX ingress controller. This is the relevant part of my ingress.yaml:

```
tls:
  - hosts:
    - myapp.com
    secretName: my-certificate
  rules:
  - host: myapp.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myapp2-service
          servicePort: 12345
        path: /myapp2/(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: myapp1-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /(.*)
```

With this setup, I can reach the frontend of myapp1 through the URL myapp.com. When I change it to

```
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myapp2-service
          servicePort: 12345
        path: /(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: myapp1-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /(.*)
```

I can reach the frontend of myapp2 through the URL myapp.com.

What I want to achieve is that I can reach the frontend of myapp1 through myapp.com and the frontend myapp.com/myapp2. Is that possible? And if so where is my mistake? As I've said, the frontend of myapp2 is basically accesible, just not through a sub-URL.

Comment: have u tried removing the(.*)?

Comment: Can You access via `myapp.com/myapp2/`? note the `/` at the end. `myapp.com/myapp2` does not match the path You configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path is configured to `/myapp2/(.*)` so `myapp.com/myapp2` does not match that.

Right now `myapp.com/myapp2` goes to `myapp1-service` looking for `/myapp2` content.

You can configure `/` at the end to be optional. But it will affect other path strings that match `myapp2`.

```
tls:
  - hosts:
    - myapp.com
    secretName: my-certificate
  rules:
  - host: myapp.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myapp2-service
          servicePort: 12345
        path: /myapp2(/|$)(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: myapp1-service
          servicePort: 80
        path: /(.*)
```

It is also possible to rewrite `myapp.com/myapp2` to `myapp.com/myapp2/` but it is little bit more complicated on free version of nginx ingress.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, I always thought slahes on the end of a URl wouldn't matter. I still get a JSON saying "Object not found" instead of the actual frontend, but I would think this is a different problem.